# extract value from loop within a loop

Tags: python, loops, for-loop

I have a list of lists and i am trying to loop through to create a new value in the second list based on two elements with the second list.

```
for line in input_list[1:]:
i = 0
for element in line:
    if i == 13:
        if line[7] > line[8]:
            line[13] == 1
        else:
            line[13] == 0
    i += 1
```

I am trying to set the value of line[13] based on the condition that line[7] is greater than line[8].

The code does not flag any errors, so syntactically it is correct, but when i print for the new list, it does not display any values (0 or 1) for line[13].

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Ed

Comment: can you please show me your list of data, that can help me to solve this.

Comment: `==` tests for equality, use a single `=` for assignment.

Comment: I do strongly recommend using a checker like "pylint". It would warn you with: `Statement seems to have no effect (pointless-statement)`.

Answer (score 3):

Use `line[13] = 1` instead of `line[13] == 1`. `==` is for comparison.

Answer (score 1):

It will not show the correct output because you haven't use assignment operator . use `line[13] = 1` instead of `line[13] == 1`
Example :- `list= [[1,2],[3,4,5]]`

For this list -

```
for line in list[1:]:
  i=0
  for element in line:
    if i==1:
       if line[0]>line[1]:
          line[1]=1
       else:
          line[1]=200
    i=i+1
```

It will work

Answer (score 0):

```
for line in input_list[1:]:
    i = 0
    for element in line:
        if i == 13:
            if line[7] > line[8]:
                line[13] = 1
            else:
                line[13] = 0
        i += 1
```

code updated